# What's the *right* event in which to call .ajax() in jquery-mobile?

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova

I'd like to populate a `listview` with data from a server.

What's the right event in the page lifecycle to do so? `pageinit`? `pagebeforeshow`? `pagebeforecreate`?

Answer (score 0):

I think right event is pageinit event. check this link

http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/docs/api/events.html

Comment: But then I have to call `$('#the-listview').listview('refresh');` after dynamically building it. I assume there's an event that is earlier in the lifecycle of the page?